# Under what circumstances can operator[] for std::map return 0?

Tags: c++, c++11, llvm

I'm working with LLVM, and I'm having issues with the following piece of code that I did not write:

```
static std::map<std::string, Value*> NamedValues;
... //Lots of other code
Value *V = NamedValues["Demo string"];
return V ? V : ErrorV("V is not in NamedValues map.");
```

From what I understand of std::map, it should never return a null pointer (Unless it's out of memory?), so I have a hard time understanding how V being 0 would indicate that V is not in the map. As is, my program is always getting an error here, but I can't figure out why. Any help on what is going on here?

Answer (score 6):

`std::map::operator []` returns a reference to the value if the key already exists, if the key does not exist, it inserts the key along with default-constructed value, and returns a reference to that value.

POD types (like pointers) have zero-initialization upon default construction. meaning that the pointer will have `nullptr` value if its default constructed.

if the key `"Demo string"` did not exist before calling `NamedValues["Demo string"];` , the map will create a default constructed pointer as value, which will be constructed as `nullptr`.

if you want to find out if the map contains a key, you need to use `find` + `end`:

```
if (map.find(yourKey) != map.end()){
  //the key exists
}
```

EDIT:
as @ShadowRanger has pointed out, `count` can be used as well.

```
if (map.count(yourKey)){
   //the key exists
}
```

Comment: [The `count` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count) is slightly more efficient than `find != end`, no? At least it's shorter: `if (map.count(yourKey)) {` which (because `map`s has unique keys) just returns `1` if found, `0` if not. Note: Up-voted, just pointing out a minor tweak that could be made.

Comment: @ShadowRanger find is more efficient if you want to use the value if it is found (which the OPs code does) because you don't need to search the map twice. The `count` method is better if you just want to know if it is in there.

Comment: @Galik: Agreed. I should have paid more attention. Doesn't help if you don't store the return value from `find` though, as in the example.

Answer (score 2):

Operator[] will return a reference to the element in the map. If not yet stored, it will create one which is default constructed.

In this case, as you are storing pointers, you will be able to get a nullptr whenever you are requesting a value for a key which is not yet in the map.